Are there any PHD scholarships in Public Policy/ Public Administration or Public Management in UK, US or Germany? For international students?
Am searching for a fully funded PHD scholarship, in Public Management, Policy or administration in US, UK or in Germany? For international students, I come from Kenya and I have a master degree in Public management from Japan,

Welcome to Academia. Unfortunately, this is what is called a shopping question, These will be closed on this site.

PhD scholarships exist in Germany, but are not the main way in which PhD students are supported in Germany (this is somewhat discipline specific though). More common is that PhD students are employed. Foreign PhD students are also eligable. So if you are interested, just apply when such a position becomes available.
